# How to get Geany working with Python?

Tags: python, geany

I'm trying to run Python 2.7 on Geany, and every time I run the code, I am getting this:

**'C:\Python27\Python"first.py"' is not recognized as an internal or external comm
and,
operable program or batch file.
Press any key to continue . . .**

I have added ;c:\Python27 to the PATH in the settings and set up the execute button in the set build commands menu.

I am new to python, and I would like to do this to learn. Please help!

Comment: could you provide the command you are using to run the python module?

Comment: Keep in mind, changes of PATH might not be applied before restarting.

Answer (score 3):

I think Geany automatically sets this up as soon as you save the file with a .py extension.

Anyway, you can try the following (I'm not using an english interface so the actual names might be a little different):

Go to `Build -> Define build commands` in the upper toolbar, then at the bottom, in `Execute commands`, you can use the following command for the `_Execute` label:

```
python "%f"
```

Then you should be able to run from the interface run button (F5). You must have python in you PATH variable for it to work, otherwise I believe you can use

```
C:\Python27\python %f
```